# Set display before indicate path into (execlp)

Tags: c, linux, executable, displayobject

I need to work with multiple displays in `execlp calls ()`. I'm trying this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("calling to execlp:\n\n");
    execlp("DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/qtdisplay","qtdisplay", "-r", NULL);
    execlp("DISPLAY=:1 /usr/bin/qtdisplay","qtdisplay", "-r", NULL);

    printf("fail!");
    exit(0);
}
```

But this fails, with the following message: `execlp: No such file or directory`
Is there any way to work with the displays?

Comment: You can't do two `execlp()`s in a row like that anyway, if the first one succeeds your original program will be gone. You can use `setenv()` to set environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try `system()` instead, it'll start a new child process and call `exec()` from there. Also, it handles shell command-line constructs by calling a shell and handing your shell construct to that shell, like this:

```
system("DISPLAY=:0; /usr/bin/qtdisplay -r");
```

Also, learn to check return codes from functions like this, and do some sane action (like print an error message):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int rc;

    rc = system("DISPLAY=:0; /usr/bin/qtdisplay -r");
    if (rc == -1) {
        perror("error starting qtdisplay on :0");
        exit(1);
    }
    rc = system("DISPLAY=:1; /usr/bin/qtdisplay -r");
    if (rc == -1) {
        perror("error starting qtdisplay on :1");
        exit(1);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

If you want these two commands to be run in parallel (not one after the other), you should use command-lines like this:

```
system("DISPLAY=:0; /usr/bin/qtdisplay -r &");
```